# Mac Keyboard Doesn't Recognize iPhone via USB

Tags: iphone, keyboard, hardware

I have a new [Mac Keyboard](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005DLDTAE) and I've successfully connected my mouse to it, however when I connect my iPhone nothing happens.  The iPhone doesn't go into a charge state and my MBP doesn't detect the iPhone.  I've tried three different cables with no difference.  Connecting directly to the MBP works fine.

Why would the keyboard support the mouse but not the iPhone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Mac Keyboard is a non-powered USB hub. As such, it may or may not recognize your iPhone when attached to it.  Just in case though, have you tried connecting it to the port that your mouse currently is in? Do this just to make sure you don't have a bum keyboard.

Comment: Good thought...yes I switched it around temporarily but no difference.  What's interesting is that I can connect my iPhone to my HP laptop via USB, and even though it won't charge it does recognize the device.

Comment: Have you tried connecting it to the back of your machine? Oh, one other thought, are you connecting this to a Mac or a PC?

Comment: iPhone -USB-> Mac keyboard -USB-> MacBook Pro.  There is no "back" USB port on my MBP.

Comment: With it being connected, go to your Apple Menu, Select "About this Mac", and select "More Info" in the pop-up.  Now, if your are running Lion, you then have to press the "System Report" button.  This brings you to a view which shows everything there.  What you will want to do is go to "USB" and check the list. You should see a "Keyboard Hub".  If you see your iPhone on that list, that means it is being seen by the computer, but not being recognized elsewhere.  If you don't see it, then this 100% confirms your suspicion. Also, have you tried a different USB cable?

Comment: BTW, when I said back of the computer, I just meant on your computer.Having an iMac, mine are on the back of my machine. :)